# Passing schema and table of ephemeral model to a macro

Tags: dbt

I have a strange problem. I'm trying to use macro to run query that will give me a list of unique dates for certain condition for a list of tables and then use that list of dates in my model. The problem is that when I try to run a query in the macro and use `{{ ref(tablexxx) }}` dbt doesn't create CTE inside macro query and I'm getting `Table "__dbt__cte__tablexxx" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table)`. the table xxx is ephemeral model (and I want it to keep it this way to avoid scanning the whole table.
jumped between call statement and run_query but in both cases the problem is the same

I have this snippet on top of my incremental model

```
{{
    get_changed_partitions_where(
        [
            {"table": stg_smt__model,
            "partition_col":'date',
            "load_time_col": 'last_updated'}
        ]
    )
}}
```

and here is my macro

```
{% macro get_changed_partitions_where(table_config) %}
    {%- call statement('date_filter', fetch_result=True) -%}
    {% for i in table_config %}
        select
            distinct cast( {{ i.partition_col }} as string)
        from {{ ref(i.table)}}
        where {{ i.load_time_col }} = current_date()
    {% if not loop.last %} UNION DISTINCT {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {%- endcall -%}
{% endmacro %}
```

What I want to achieve is to pass `dataset.tablexxx` to the macro (can be as string, I don't know no matter what I do it ends up being a None or  string `__dbt__cte__tablexxx` without a proper CTE on the top.

tablexxx is basically a `tablexxx.sql` with `select * from source('src1', 'tablexxx'`. I want to have it ephemeral to make sure only required partitions are scanned.

Comment: Can you please add a bit more context on `tablexxx`? Is it a table created by a DBT model or some external process?

Comment: Edited question:

tablexxx is basically a tablexxx.sql with select * from source('src1', 'tablexxx'. I want to have it ephemeral to make sure only required partitions are scanned.

Comment: According to https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/materializations#ephemeral, it's not possible to `ref` an ephemeral model. Not really sure about the underlying database, but have you considered using views?

Comment: yes I was thinking about it but I can't use views because then it would scan the whole table in the downstream models. I'm okay with not using `ref` in the default form, just trying to find a way to extract source and table from it (and unfortunately it's much harder than I thought it would be)

Comment: What if the date filter is part of the view? Is it also possible that what you're trying to achieve is solvable using incremental models?

Comment: I'm actually trying to be precise regarding data usage for incremental projects. I have 3+ data sources for a table. I want to pull only partitions required but to be able to do that I need to check all source tables and what partitions got updated since the last run.